# AmqpConnectException: ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-rabbit

Trying out Spring Cloud to send messages to RabbitMQ following a tutorial by Josh Long on Youtube.

**OS: Windows**

GIT URL:
https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-microservices/tree/master/bootiful-microservices-edgware

I imported the reservation-client, eureka-service, config-service. I was successfully able to start up all the services.

Every time I hit the service with a JSON payload, I am getting the below error message.

Input URL: http://localhost:9999/reservations
Body: `{"reservationName":"Dr.Who"}`

Output JSON:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1521277278436,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException",
    "message": "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect",
    "path": "/reservations"
}
```

I am getting the below error in the console.

```
2018-03-17 02:00:43.401  INFO [reservation-client,,,] 6188 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 9999
2018-03-17 02:00:43.408  INFO [reservation-client,,,] 6188 --- [           main] c.example.ReservationClientApplication   : Started ReservationClientApplication in 36.047 seconds (JVM running for 36.941)
2018-03-17 02:01:15.851  INFO [reservation-client,,,] 6188 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-17 02:01:15.854  INFO [reservation-client,,,] 6188 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-17 02:01:16.034  INFO [reservation-client,,,] 6188 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 180 ms
2018-03-17 02:01:16.116  WARN [reservation-client,65c06760307f62f8,65c06760307f62f8,true] 6188 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : No routes found from RouteLocator
2018-03-17 02:01:18.316 ERROR [reservation-client,65c06760307f62f8,65c06760307f62f8,true] 6188 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Uncaught exception thrown

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

I am getting a connection error even if I use Kafka, instead of RabbitMQ binder.

Can somebody help? All the examples seemed to have been implemented on unix based platform. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means you either haven't installed RabbitMQ, or it's not running on the default (localhost:5672). Same thing with Kafka, you need to install and run a broker.

I see Josh provides a docker-compose.yml to run RabbitMQ in a docker image, or you can just install RabbitMQ as a service.

Comment: I've not installed RabbitMQ or Kafka. I am using the appropriate binders, hence I'm guessing I don't need to install RabbitMQ or Kafka? Can I make this work without actually installing RabbitMQ or Kafka?

Comment: No; you cannot; the binder "binds" destinations to the broker which must exist. [Spring for Apache Kafka](https://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/) provides an embedded kafka broker (usually used for testing) which is possible because Kafka is written in Scala and runs in the JVM. RabbitMQ is written in Erlang and can't run in a JVM. The [spring-cloud-stream-samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) has a sample showing how to test with an embedded kafka broker.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll install RabbitMQ and continue. Thank you for the suggestion on embedded Kafka as well :)